# JavaScript global callback functions are not called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, javascript-objects

I'm building a small web app with a few other people. I want to allow the other developers to define a couple of functions that are always called when the document is ready.

Our app inserts the following script into the HTML body of every page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(){
    window.Utils = {
      funcs: {}
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
      alert('Calling funcs...');

      var startFunc = Utils.funcs['start'];
      if (startFunc != undefined){
        startFunc();
      }

      var finishFunc = Utils.funcs['finish'];
      if (finishFunc != undefined){
        finishFunc();
      }
    });
  })();
</script>
```

Then, in a separate .js file, a developer should be able to do the following:

```
Utils.funcs['start'] = function(){
    alert('Starting...');
};

Utils.funcs['finish'] = function(){
    alert('Finishing...');
};
```

But this doesn't work. The functions are never called?

jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/XvQtF/

Answer (score 3):

jsFiddle's *(very surprising)* default is to put your code in a `window` `load` handler. (You can see this on the left at the top, the second drop-down box says "onload".) That happens **very** late in the loading process, long after `ready` has fired. So the functions aren't added until after you've tried to run them.

If the other developers put their functions in `Utils.funcs` in `script` elements after your element defining `Utils` but without waiting for a `load` event, it's fine: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XvQtF/1/)

---

For what it's worth, though, I would lean toward using a pub/sub solution rather than a single function. If you want to have more than one `start` function, for instance, your current structure doesn't allow it.

jQuery has `Deferred` and `Promise` now, which can be used for this. Here's a simple example of that: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/iceruf/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/iceruf/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Pub/Sub with Deferred and Promise</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    (function($) {
      // Deferred objects for our app states
      var start = new $.Deferred(),
          finish = new $.Deferred();

      window.Utils = {
        start: start.promise(),   // Only expose the Promise of each
        finish: finish.promise()  // " " " " " "
      };

      $(function() {
        alert("Calling funcs...");

        // Start the app
        start.resolve();

        // Finish the app (or whatever)
        finish.resolve();
      });

    })(jQuery);
  </script>
  <script>
    // Module 1
    Utils.start.then(function() {
      alert("Module 1 Started!");
    });
    Utils.finish.then(function() {
      alert("Module 1 Finished!");
    });
  </script>
  <script>
    // Module 2
    Utils.start.then(function() {
      alert("Module 2 Started!");
    });
    Utils.finish.then(function() {
      alert("Module 2 Finished!");
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up Utils in a separate script to be loaded as the very first one. Also, do this unconditionally (not in any callback etc):

```
/* load as first script, sets up a global container-object for later use */
var Utils = {
  funcs: {}
}
```

Note that it is ok to define a global variable in the global scope.

```
/* other script */
(function(){
  function myFunc() { /*...*/ };

  // now store a reference in Utils
  Utils.funcs.start = myFunc;
})();
```

As mentioned in an other answer: Be aware of the loading and calling order of your various scripts / code:

$(document).ready is essentially the "DOMContentLoaded"-event with most browsers (but earlier versions of IE). "DOMContentLoaded" fires, when all inline-resources originally found in the head-section have been loaded and the DOM-structure of the body is present.
Since this does not include any injected content, it is probably granted, that the event is fired before any modular library (which are loading modules by injecting script tags) is fully loaded and present. (Given that these scripts are loading concurrently with images and other inline-stuff using just a handful of network-slots/sockets provided by the browser, they are probably one of the last things to be ready in your whole loading-process.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just using

```
 startFunc() and 
 finishFunc()
```

try using this

```
 startFunc.apply(this, null) and 
 finishFunc.apply(this, null)
```

this will invoke the functions.

also make sure that

```
 Utils.funcs['start']
 Utils.funcs['finish']
```

is getting initialized before they are called.